# How do I marshal a C# string array to a VB6 array?

Tags: c#, com, vb6, c++-cli, marshalling

I have a VB6 app that uses a C# COM DLL. In managed C++ I can write a function as follows:

```
array<String^>^ GetAManagedArray()
{
    //Do stuff and return a managed array
}
```

I can then assign the returned managed array to an array in VB6:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim strArray() As String
    strArray = myComObject.GetAManagedArray
End Sub
```

This works fine in C++, but in C# the `System.Array` object is abstract and I can't seem to find the managed equivalent to the C++ `array<>^`. Also, in C# just returning `string[]` does not work.

What is the managed array equivalent in C#?

**EDIT: Here is the exact code I have for the fucntions**
The C# COM function:

```
public string[] OneTwoThree()
{
    return new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
}
```

The VB6 function:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim test As New ComObjectCSharp
    Dim strArr(), strTemp As String
    strArr = test.OneTwoThree
    strTemp = strArr(0) & " " & strArr(1) & " " & strArr(2)
    MsgBox strTemp
End Sub
```

The code fails on the fourth line of the VB6 code with the error **"Compile error: Can't assign to array"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strArr() variable is not actually an array of strings.  It is an array of variants.  Fix:

```
Dim strArr() As String
strArr = test.OneTwoThree
```

Now it is the same as your first snippet.

Comment: Thanks. Works now! I thought that in VB "Dim a, b, c As String" was the same as C# "string a, b, c;" Didn't realize you had to explicitly specify type to each one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the C# syntax to create an array it's `new string[5]` for an array of length 5, initialised with nulls or `new string[] { "one", "two" }` for an array with the specified values.

Aside from that, you'd have to be more specific about what "doesn't work" for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be test.OneTwoThree returns a single string not an array of strings. 
Try `Dim strArr` instead of `Dim strArr()` 
If that works you have to find out what is the delimiter that the proxy for the C# function 
returned (sometimes marshaling of arrays doesn't necessary get proper/expected termination in client 
code enviournment)

Comment: OneTwoThree does return an array of strings. I tested it.